# How to do a specific task after some time

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, microchip

I have to switch on one relay after some specific time, but at same time I have to do continuous polling for controlling other relays, I am already using interrupt for multiplexing purpose (7 segment display). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your existing interrupt to increment a counter.  You should know the period of your existing interrupt already, so divide your required time by that period and that's the number of counts of your counter you need to check for.

For instance, if your multiplexing interrupt happens once every 5ms and you need to wait 10 seconds, then you would wait for your counter to count up to (10 / 0.005 = ) 2000.  When you see your counter exceed that value you would then reset the counter and perform your periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a free timer, the simplest way is to have a second interrupt fired by a timer. If your processor supports interrupt priorities this is even better since you can have the timer trigger be higher priority than your other interrupt and you would be assured to always have the same latency down to a few clock cycles (1 or 2 if I am not mistaken).

Its a little hard to be more specific since we don't even know what processor family you are using.